# Cannot create a Elasticache cluster in sa-east-1 region using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm trying to create a Redis Elasticache cluster using boto in the sa-east-1 region, and boto is giving me this error message:

```
{"Error":{"Code":"InvalidParameterValue","Message":"sa-east-1 is not a valid availability zone.","Type":"Sender"},"RequestId":"2q34hj192-6902-11e4-8b4a-afafaefasefsadfsadf"}
```

with this code:

```
from boto.elasticache.layer1 import ElastiCacheConnection
self.elasticache = ElastiCacheConnection()
boto.elasticache.connect_to_region(
        'sa-east-1a',
        aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_KEY
    )
elasticache.create_cache_cluster(
        cache_cluster_id='test1',
        engine='redis',
        cache_node_type='cache.m3.medium',
        num_cache_nodes=1,
        preferred_availability_zone='sa-east-1',
 )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in boto code, I found that

```
elasticache = boto.elasticache.connect_to_region(
         'sa-east-1',
        aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_KEY
    )
elasticache.create_cache_cluster(
        cache_cluster_id=cache_cluster_id,
        engine=engine,
        cache_node_type=cache_node_type,
        num_cache_nodes=num_cache_nodes,
        preferred_availability_zone='sa-east-1a',
        preferred_maintenance_window=preferred_maintenance_window,
    )
```

works.

Comment: How is that different than what I suggested?  I'm confused.

Comment: There is a difference in the two calls: one of my first and wrong code, and the answer, where one call uses region, as you pointed, but the second uses availability zones. Put the code so this is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

It's asking you for an availability zone but you are providing it with a region.  Correct values would be one of `sa-east-1a` or `sa-east-1b` or just leave it blank if you have no preference.